# Защитить приложение от чистки статических переменных

Tags: java, android

Написано приложение для android на java оно должно быть не закрываемым. Сейчас тестировали на Android 6.0 Marshmallow свернув приложения, спустя некоторое время, пользуясь другими приложениями, щёлкаем по ярлыку нашего приложения и оно открывается в том же Активити, что и была но с пустыми статическими переменными. Можно ли как то защитить статические переменные от их чистки системой?

Comment: А что значит "оно должно быть не закрываемым"?..

Comment: Если вы свернули приложение, оно как минимум уходит в состояние паузы. Если вам нужно чтобы выполнялись какие-то процессы когда приложение свернуто создайте сервис в приложении и реализуйте в нем логику. А касательно переменных, то их нужно сохранять при вызове методов onPause, onStop и onDestroy, и загружать последние данные в методе onCreate/onResume если их не много, можно использоваться `SharedPreferecnes` если же много то записывать в БД и получать значения оттуда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, статические переменные никак нельзя защитить от чистки системой - на процесс сборки мусора Вы не очень-то сможете повлиять. Но вообще время жизни статических переменных привязывается к времени жизни приложения, поэтому лучше вообще не использовать статические переменные в `Activity`:

> Время жизни статических переменных привязывается к времени жизни
>   приложения и соответственно память из-под них освободиться тогда,
>   когда виртуальная машина выкинет из памяти ваше приложение, а если,
>   например, работает сервис, то произойти это может не скоро,
>   переменные будут висеть и отжирать память.

Лучше сохранять ЗНАЧЕНИЯ (которые Вы храните сейчас в этих переменных) куда-либо для длительного хранения - например, в базу данных, в файл либо в `SharedPreferecnes`, либо как вариант сохранять в `Bundle` в методе `onSaveInstanceState`.

P.S. А то, что у Вас открывается "Активити, что и была, но с пустыми статическими переменными" - скорее всего, следствие того, что где-то эти переменные всё же очищаются в приложении.

Comment: Статические переменные в классе `Application` работают точно также как и в классе `Activity`. Как и в любом другом классе. Потому они и статические (принадлежат не объекту класса, а самому классу). Если просто умрёт активити (например, вызвали `finish()`), то её статическая переменная не очистится. Если умрёт весь процесс приложения, то тут никакая статика не выживет.

Comment: @eugeneek, да, Вы правы, про то, что  статические переменные при пересоздании Активити будут очищаться - это я неправильно написала. Изменила ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Почему не будет работать как вы описали - ответили [здесь.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944369/android-static-object-lifecycle)

Для того чтоб увидеть ваши данные снова их необходимо сохранить в методе **onPause**, переопределите этот метод в вашей *Activity*. После чего для сохранения ваших значений можно воспользоваться одним из следующих способов:

- Shared Preferences
- Files
- Databases
- Content Providers

Также рекомендую прочитать официальную документацию, в которой есть примеры и более точное описание. Ссылка на офф. документацию: [Storage Options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)